# WiFi Hotspot on Mac or Windows

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mac, hotspot

I am trying to set up WiFi hotspot using my MacBook pro laptop. I have both Mac OS and Windows 7 installed.

The problem is that my network provider (eduroam, university network) does not allow users to create hotspots and has some kind of protection that prevents me from creating one. I tried using builtin OS network sharing tool (System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing -> WiFi) but created WiFi does not provide internet access (Error message: DNS server does not respond).

Is there a tool - either for mac or for windows - that would be able to bypass this protection?

Comment: When you created the hotspot using the "built-in OS" di you try to specify your own DNS server address? You could try setting Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) which may work?

Comment: How can I do that? I don't see this option :/

Comment: Ok I have changed it and it does not work